# Azure Billing Usage API not returning additional properties

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api

I am following [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usagedetails/list#usagedetailslist) to get my usage details for azure account. As per the official documentation, by using $expand=properties/additional properties should return additional properties (such as consumed service, cost center etc) in result set. However I am getting the same output irrespective of using expand in url.

URLs used are as below

**Without expand :** 
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2018-06-30&

**With expand :**
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2018-06-30&$expand=properties/additionalProperties

Both the requests are returning same result set. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the API only returns summarized usage information with a meter ID. If you want additional information on the meter, or additional information about the resource, you will need to add the expand parameter with the appropriate value:

- Expanded meter information: properties/meterDetails
- Expanded properties bag: properties/additionalProperties

You may try Sample Call for Additional Details:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2018-03-31&$expand=properties/additionalProperties
```

Please note that additionalProperties field will show up only when some additional data is available. For most cases, in general, there is no additional data. If some information is always expected to be available in additionalProperties, then it should be part of properties field in response and not the additionalProperties. additionalProperties is only for displaying some special/edge case information, which is not a candidate for a the main properties field.

The additionalProperties field will be present in response, if there are some additional info available to show, else it will be omitted to optimize the response payload size.

Comment: Please read my question carefully. adding expand parameter is not making any difference to the result set.

Comment: Through API i do not see the consumedService property in json response, but when i download the usage report from azure portal it shows consumedService and has values also. What could be the reason for the same

Answer (score 0):

Try using this API this works for me:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{Subsid}/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/202204/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?$expand=meterDetails,additionalProperties&metric=AmortizedCost&api-version=2019-05-01
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/reservations/charge-back-usage#get-azure-consumption-and-reservation-usage-data-using-api)